# Facing issues in building a C++ shared library for multiple architectures (x86_64, armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386)

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I'm totally confused and in need of help from someone who has created C++ shared library that will work on any platform using any IDE.

What i have done so far:

1) Created a shared library using cmake in Ubuntu.

2) Transferred source files and Makefile (cmake) to MacOSX (El Capitan)

3) Created the build directory

4) Using Terminal in Mac OS, i ran :

```
$ cmake ..
$ sudo make install
```

5) Created an Xcode iOS Project that support armv7 and arm64 architectures

6) Used header search path and library search path to find the headers and library i had installed in

```
/usr/local/include/
```

and

```
/usr/local/lib
```

7) Used one of the included one of the library header file in main.mm (renamed main.m) and created an object for the class

8) Build the project gives me error because of following reason

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libMyLibrary.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /usr/local/lib/libMyLibrary.dylib
```

## Here are the contents of my cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lsqlite3")

#Adding source files
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

#Generate the shared library from the sources
add_library(MyLibraryName SHARED ${SOURCES})

target_compile_options(MyLibraryFolder PRIVATE -std=c++11 -lsqlite3)

add_executable(MyLibraryName ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(MyLibraryName PRIVATE -lsqlite3)

#Set the location for library installation. Use "sudo make install" to apply
install(TARGETS MyLibraryName DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)

install(DIRECTORY inc/${MyLibraryName_CPP} DESTINATION /usr/local/include)
```

---

Can anyone help me with this, Please...

Comment: @halfelf - thanks for modifications. im new to this, so this is indeed great help.

Comment: I can't speak to OSX's compiler and variants. But hopefully this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html#Submodel-Options might be able to point you closer to your intended target. Also, I would look for cross-compilers as well, as the link I have supplied may not be what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your step 4, you're compiling the library on MacOS, which is `x86_64`; you can NOT just copy it to iOS's project, because iOS uses `arm64`.

So you should cross-compile the library for `arm64` and use it for your iOS project.

Comment: I am new to cross-compiling, can you please suggest any methods or links that can help me with the same.